# How to represent Infinity in floating/double values in C++?

Tags: c++, ieee-754, infinite

As [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity#:%7E:text=std%3A%3Anumeric_limits%3A%3Ainfinity&text=In%20IEEE%20754%2C%20the%20most,bits%20of%20the%20fraction%20cleared.) says "In IEEE 754, the most common binary representation of floating-point numbers, the positive infinity is the value with all bits of the exponent set and all bits of the fraction cleared.". I tried this code snippet, but I don't see exponent bits set. Am I wrong somewhere?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <bitset>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    float a = 0b00000000000000000000000000000000;

    double b = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    bitset<64> x(b);

    cout<<x<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It prints 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 on console.

Comment: `bitset<64> x(b)` - this uses the constructor `std::bitset::bitset(unsigned long long)`.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. You're making a `long` from a `double` here. I'm not sure if that's even defined behaviour for infinity.

Comment: @Thomas: My compiler warnings are turned way up, and Apple Clang 11.0 does not report any warnings.

Comment: Hm, indeed! Neither gcc nor clang warns about this even with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. Then why do I remember seeing warnings along the lines of "making integer from float without a cast"?

Comment: You have to add `-Wconversion` to see those warnings.

Comment: @IlCapitano or `-Wfloat-conversion`

Answer (score 5):

`std::bitset` doesn't have a constructor accepting a `double`. When you pass `double`, you instead invoke the constructor that accepts `unsigned long long` and the `double` is first implicitly converted to `unsigned long long`.

Problem is, `unsigned long long` cannot represent infinity, and the behaviour of the program is consequently undefined. Standard says:

> [conv.fpint]
>
> A prvalue of a floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type.
> The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded.
> **The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.**

---

To see the bits, you can first "bitcast" the floating point to an integer type, and then pass that integer to bitset:

```
auto int_b = std::bit_cast<std::uint64_t>(b);
std::bitset<64> x(int_b);
```

Comment: Aha, sd::bit_cast - learn something every day

Answer (score 1):

> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Really?

Mine prints

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <bitset>

const char NL = '\n';

int main() {
    typedef union {
        double   d;
        uint64_t u;
    } du;

    du b;
    
    b.d = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    std::bitset<64> x(b.d);

    std::cout << x << " " << b.u << NL;
    std::cout << std::bitset<64>(b.u) << NL;
    return 0;
}
```

1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 9218868437227405312

and last line prints

0111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Yes, UB, I know, I know

Comment: 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 isn't the representation of infinity either though.

Comment: @eerorika I agree. I added output for infinity bit representation.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
bitset<64> x(b);
```

implicitly converts `b` to an `unsigned long long` (or `unsigned long` prior to C++11) to invoke the [`bitset(unsigned long long)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset) constructor of `std::bitset`.

Note that when converting between a floating point type and an integral type, the behavior is undefined if value cannot be represented in the destination type (N4659 7.10/1). So, creating a bitset in this way could lead to *anything* being printed.